# Rails Activerecord .create weird null error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, null

Weird null error.

I have a /lib/task rake script that refuses to set a string value, when I run it rake reports this output/error:

Purchase

Purchase

PGError: ERROR:  null value in column "type" violates not-null constraint
: INSERT INTO "account_logs" ("sum", "type", "usertype", "transaction_id", "commited", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at")
VALUES (168.0, NULL, 'Public', 452921, 't', 10146
, '2011-07-29 09:57:11.514472', '2011-08-02 15:33:38.479838') RETURNING "id"
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:207:in `rescue in log'

Which is very very strange since I actually set value which clearly is not NULL. How come???

My code is this:

```
  m_sum = Float(rand_int(1,500))
  m_type = "Purchase"

  puts m_type

  m_user_info = UserInfo.order("RANDOM()").first
  m_usertype = m_user_info.usertype
  m_transactionid=gid
  m_commited=true
  m_user_id=rand_int(1,User.count)
  m_created_at=rand_time(1.week.ago,Time.now)
  m_updated_at=Time.now

  if m_type.nil?
    puts "What the f"
  end
  puts m_type

  AccountLog.create(
    :sum               => m_sum,
    :type              => m_type,
    :usertype          => m_usertype,
    :game              => m_game,
    :transactionid     => m_transactionid,
    :commited          => m_commited,
    :user_id           => m_user_id,
    :created_at        => m_created_at,
    :updated_at        => m_updated_at
  )

#part of schema.rb
create_table "accountlogs", :force => true do |t|
  t.decimal  "sum",               :precision => 15, :scale => 10, :null => false
  t.string   "type",              :limit => 30, :null => false
  t.string   "usertype",          :limit => 30, :null => false
  t.integer  "transactionid",     :limit => 8,  :null => false
  t.boolean  "commited",                        :null => false
  t.integer  "user_id",           :limit => 8,  :null => false
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

#Model

class AccountLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Please post the code of your model AccountLog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` appears to be a reserved, although deprecated, keyword in ruby.

You probably want to rename your attribute to something else.

Comment: class AccountLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'type' as an attribute. According to the link below, 'type' may be a reserved word in the ruby language, and could cause some issues like the one you're experiencing.

[List of Reserved Words](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords)

You can see that 'type' is at the bottom, in the 'other words that have caused trouble'.

Comment: ardavis, not sure I got that one. What do you mean?

Comment: That was it. When I changed the column name it all works. Quite missleading error though. Should't the interpetor have caught that one long before SQL strings where created?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have an answer to that. But please make sure you mark the correct answer as the answer, and please vote up any helpful responses. Glad you got it working!